# Change TActionManager Style at runtime?

Tags: delphi

I have a TActionManager on my Form.

I would like to from code at runtime be able to change the style of the Action Manager between 'Platform Default' 'and XP Style' etc.

When I try any of the below:

```
ActionManager1.Style := 'Platform Default';
ActionManager1.Style := 'XP Style';
```

I get the following error:

> Left side cannot be assigned to

I can only assume this property is read-only by the error message.

Is there a workaround, or something I might be missing as to how to change the Action Manager style at runtime?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm slightly confused by the error message you report. That is not the error message that your code produces. The error message that is actually reported, for the code in your question, is:

> E2010 Incompatible types: 'TActionBarStyle' and 'string'

Leaving that aside, the correct syntax for setting an action manager style at runtime is this:

```
ActionManager1.Style := PlatformDefault;
ActionManager1.Style := XPStyle;
ActionManager1.Style := StandardStyle;
```

Note that the `Style` property is of type `TActionBarStyle`. There are various instances of `TActionBarStyle` descendents defined in the VCL, one per registered style.

These instances are all global variables defined in the interface section of a unit, one unit per instance. To gain access to these style objects you will need to `use` the following units:

- `Vcl.PlatformDefaultStyleActnCtrls` for the `PlatformDefault` style.
- `Vcl.XPStyleActnCtrls` for the `XPStyle` style.
- `Vcl.StdStyleActnCtrls` for  the `StandardStyle` style.

<sub>You will need to omit the `Vcl` prefix on older versions of Delphi.</sub>

The form designer uses a piece of magic to make the style look like a string in the Object Inspector. It has been implemented this way to make it feasible for you to register your own styles.

Comment: I wondered what Vcl. was for but I guess that must be XE2 as I am using XE. I can't believe I didn't think of trying to call it like you and RRUZ have shown! As you said, I think because I saw it in the Object Inspector as 'Platform Default' I assumed it was a string. And now that you mentioned it I payed closer attention from the code editor - ActionManager1.Style is of TActionBarStyle, again as you pointed out. Sometimes I just miss the complete obvious, I am still learning though! :) I accepted your answer because of the extra detail and information.

Comment: Yes, `Vcl.` is the new unit namespace prefixes in XE2. You just omit them for XE. You had me confused with your reported compiler error message though. I'm sure it didn't say what you said it did!  ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You must assign a `TActionBarStyle` descendent in the [Style](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ActnMan.TCustomActionManager.Style) property.

Try this (the XPStyle is a global variable declared in the XPStyleActnCtrls unit )

```
  ActionManager1.Style:=XPStyle;
```